# Trying to use a data-only SIM card in an iPhone 7 running iOS 10

Tags: iphone, cellular-data, sim, android, apple-configurator

So, I recently got an Android tablet (Samsung Tab E 8) from my carrier (Virgin Mobile in Canada) and it came with a nano sim card on a $15/month 3GB data plan. I’d way rather use this in my iPhone 7 than my current plan, and I've been trying for days with no success. I've established thus far that I need to change the APN settings to do this, but my carrier has blocked my ability to access these natively in settings>cellular>cellular options. I also attempted third-party solutions like unlockit.co.nz, which simply didn't work. I've moved on now to using Apple Configurator 2 on my Mac to create a custom configuration profile to change my APN settings directly, but all the APN info for Virgin Canada I can find online is not successful, and neither is the info I can find on the Android tablet. I've seen plenty of questions here and elsewhere about using iPad SIMs in iPhones, but I can't find anything with Android devices. In short, does anyone here know a bit more about this process, and (1) is it even possible to use this previously Android sim with my iPhone, (2) if so, any idea how?

I’ll add that in Canada, Virgin Mobile uses Bell Mobility networks to service all of there customers, and retain no network of their own.

- Virgin Mobile’s sole page on APN connections http://www.virginmobile.ca/en/members-lounge/getting-started/phone/sim.html
- Site with more Virgin APN settings, some the same as above, some different https://apn-canada.gishan.net/settings/os_41_2_ios_10ios_10_internet_and_mms_settings_for_virgin_mobile.php